# Constructors not Creating Object -- Java

Tags: java, object, constructor

I've been wrestling with this problem in one of my programs for about a week now, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
For this assignment I'm basically making an array of Employee objects with 3 different types of employees (commission, salary, hourly). All three of the sub-classes extend the Employee class, which is abstract.

Here is my code that calls the constructors for each class type:

```
    public boolean addEmployee(int empType, String first, String last, char mi, char gen, int empNum, boolean full, double amount)
    {
    employeeCount += 1;

    if (employeeCount > EMPLOYEES_MAX) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: ARRAY FULL. UNABLE TO ADD NEW EMPLOYEE");
        return false;
    }

    else {
        switch (empType) {
            case 1:
            employees[employeeCount] = new HourlyEmployee(first, last, mi, gen, empNum, full, amount);
            break;

            case 2:
            employees[employeeCount] = new SalaryEmployee(first, last, mi, gen, empNum, full, amount);
            break;

            case 3:
            employees[employeeCount] = new CommissionEmployee(first, last, mi, gen, empNum, full, amount);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the constructor for the salary employee, the other 2 are pretty much teh same as this.

```
public class SalaryEmployee extends Employee
{
private double salary;

public SalaryEmployee(String first, String last, char midInit, char gen, int empNum, boolean full, double sal)
{
    super(first, last, midInit, gen, empNum, full);
    salary = sal;
}
```

The super constructor I have written which is called by this constructor follows:

```
abstract class Employee
{
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected char middleInitial;
protected boolean fullTime;
protected char gender;
protected int employeeNum;

public Employee(String first, String last, char midInit, char gen, int empNum, boolean full)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    middleInitial = midInit;
    employeeNum = empNum;
    fullTime = full;

    switch (gen) {
        case 'M': case 'F': 
        case 'm': case 'f':
        gender = gen;
        break;

        default:
        gender = 'F';
    }
}
```

As I've said before, I have no idea why its not creating the objects like it should. Whenever I go to print out the array or sort it or anything I always get either null or a null pointer exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you all so much!

EDIT:

Ok, heres where my Employee array is initialized.

```
public class EmployeeList
{
private final int EMPLOYEES_MAX = 50;
private Employee employees[];
private int employeeCount;

public EmployeeList()
{
    employees = new Employee[EMPLOYEES_MAX];
    employeeCount = 0;
}
```

When I run it its like its still going through the constructors because the default method is not run, I just get null for some odd reason. Heres the output:

Choose from the following options:
        1       Add Employee
        2       Process Employees by Type Submenu
        3       Remove Employee
        4       Sort Employees
        5       Calculate Weekly Payout
        6       Calculate Bonus
        7       Annual Raises
        8       Reset Week
        0       Quit
        Option: 1

1. Hourly
2. Salary
3. Commission
   Enter Choice: 1

Enter Last Name: Doe

Enter First Name: Jane

Enter Middle Initial: M

Enter Gender: F

Enter Employee Number: 1

Full Time? (y/n): y

Enter wage: 14

Employee Added to List

null

Main Menu

The null comes from my main class that calls a listAll() method, its supposed to list everything in the array. but instead just returns null.

EDIT AGAIN:

So here is the method that is supposed to list everything.

```
    public void listAll()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < employeeCount; x++)
        System.out.println(employees[x]);
}
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: In your `addEmployee` switch statement, add a case at the end like `default: System.out.println(empType); break;` and post the output here.

Comment: Also, I need you to post the declaration and initialization of your employees array. Since you didn't pass it in, I assume you declared and initialized it somewhere else.

Comment: Can you please stop editing your question in ways that completely invalidate the answers posted thus far? That's just rude.

Comment: Ok, we're making progress. Your cases ARE being hit correctly, but the method that prints the list is simply returning null. Now can you please post the method that prints the list (I assume it is called `listAll()`)?

Comment: Added a third problem to my answer.

Comment: If your problem still hasn't been solved, I'd suggest posting the code where you actually call `listAll()`. I noticed that nothing posted so far has been inside of a `static` method, so all of this code is really just kind of "floating around" somewhere to the rest of us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Problem**

You passed in `int empType`, then switched on `employeeType`

**Second Problem**

You passed in `int empType`, but all of the cases in your switch are `char`, like `case '1':`.

Edit: You edited your question to fix some of the problems >:-/

**Third Problem**

In your `listAll()` method, you are attempting to print an object that has no `toString()` method. Give your abstract Employee class a `toString()` method like the following.

```
public String toString() {
    return lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleInitial;
}
```

Now, imagine you want your child classes to have a more detailed representation like "*Smith, John C. is hourly.*" You can do this by adding ANOTHER `toString` method to each of your children classes, but you get to reuse the part you already wrote! For example, this would go in your hourly employee class.

```
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " is hourly.";
}
```

Comment: I actually edited that for readability, its the right way in my program. Also switched the switches, still not working. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind but most of them regard the overall design and not your specific question.

### Off By One

The way your code looks at the moment it contains an [off by one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). You're initializing `employeeCount` to `0` but you're incrementing it to `1` before the first insert. Hence the *first* employee goes into the *second* array slot at `employees[1]`.

But your output loop is correct and after the first insert, it only outputs `employees[0]`, which is still `null`. Just move the `employeeCount += 1;` to the end of the method and you're fine.

(In case that isn't clear: Java counts array indices from `0` to `length-1`.)

### IndexOutOfBounds

There's another bug. You're comparing `employeeCount > EMPLOYEES_MAX`. If `employeeCount = EMPLOYEES_MAX`, it passes the test but inserting at `employees[EMPLOYEES_MAX]` will fail because it is out of the array's bounds.

You ave to check for `employeeCount >= EMPLOYEES_MAX`. This might seem counter intuitive because in your method you used it as *"number of employees after this insert"*. If you include my correction from above, the interpretation is *"number of employees already inserted"*.

Comment: Oh my gosh..I moved the employeeCount += 1 to the end of the method like you suggested and it fixed it. This is outrageously awesome!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @lindgrenj6 : I'm still collecting reputation. Could you please upvote this answer and consider checking it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Change `case '1'` to `case 1` and so on, you clearly don't want to switch on char values, when you pass in an int.

Comment: Ok fixed that, still giving me null when I run it. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see where the array of employees you fill is coming from. Also, have you used a debugger to see that the correct cases are stepped into?

Comment: I declare it in the EmployeeList constructor method, EmployeeList is the class that handles the array apparently. It looks like this.

employees = new Employee[EMPLOYEES_MAX];

what debugger would you recommend?

Comment: I worked with eclipse for a long time, it's free and it worked.

Comment: Ok might have to give it a try. Never used eclipse before haha just been using vim.

Answer (score 0):

I have joined what you have written until now and looks that it works (constants introduced for code readability):

```
public class EmployeeList {

public static final int EMP_TYPE_HOURLY = 1;
public static final int EMP_TYPE_SALARY = 2;
public static final int EMP_TYPE_COMMISSION = 3;
public static final char EMP_GEN_MALE = 'M';
public static final char EMP_GEN_FEMALE = 'F';

private int employeeCount = 0;
private static final int EMPLOYEES_MAX = 5;
private Employee[] employees = new Employee[EMPLOYEES_MAX];

public boolean addEmployee(int empType, String first, String last, char mi, char gen, int empNum, boolean full, double amount) {
    employeeCount += 1;

    if (employeeCount > EMPLOYEES_MAX) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: ARRAY FULL. UNABLE TO ADD NEW EMPLOYEE");
        return false;
    } else {
        switch (empType) {
            case EMP_TYPE_HOURLY:
                employees[employeeCount] = new HourlyEmployee(first, last, mi, gen, empNum, full, amount);
                break;

            case EMP_TYPE_SALARY:
                employees[employeeCount] = new SalaryEmployee(first, last, mi, gen, empNum, full, amount);
                break;

            case EMP_TYPE_COMMISSION:
                employees[employeeCount] = new CommissionEmployee(first, last, mi, gen, empNum, full, amount);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public Employee[] getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmployeeList empList = new EmployeeList();

    empList.addEmployee(EMP_TYPE_HOURLY, null, null, 'A', EMP_GEN_MALE, 555, true, 100.0);
    empList.addEmployee(EMP_TYPE_HOURLY, null, null, 'A', EMP_GEN_FEMALE, 555, true, 100.0);
    empList.addEmployee(EMP_TYPE_SALARY, null, null, 'A', EMP_GEN_FEMALE, 555, true, 100.0);
    empList.addEmployee(EMP_TYPE_COMMISSION, null, null, 'A', EMP_GEN_FEMALE, 555, true, 100.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEES_MAX; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + empList.getEmployees()[i]);
    }
}
```

}